# Using an FSM, how do you clean up state related attributes that may be used from several states?

Tags: architecture, ai, state, behavior, fsm

I'm making a game that plays a bit like Diablo, but you can harvest resources like in an RTS.

I have the following states in my FSM: `IdleState`, `ApproachingTargetCoordinateState`, `ApproachingTargetEntityState`, `CuttingTreeState`.

When a user clicks a tree, `Player.targetEntity` is set to the corresponding `Tree` instance (which inherits from `Entity`) and the player's state is set to `ApproachingTargetEntityState`. When the player reaches the tree, a transition is made to `CuttingTreeState`. Shortly after, the tree is cut down, and state is changed back to `IdleState`.

At this point, I'd like the `Player.targetEntity` reference to be removed because its no longer needed. Where should I put the logic that does this?

I could do this in the `CuttingTreeState#exit()` method but that would only work in situations where everything happens as described above. If for instance the user clicks a random coordinate (not a tree) before the player reaches `CuttingTreeState`, `CuttingTreeState#exit()` is never run and so `Player.targetEntity` is never removed.

I can't put it in `ApproachingTargetEntityState#exit()` either, as that would remove the reference to the tree before we get to `CuttingTreeState`.

Another solution would be to just not care about `Player.targetEntity`. But it just feels wrong to me that the attribute is set for example when the player is in the `IdleState`.

How can I solve this problem? What is usually done?

Comment: How about clearing it on entry to the `IdleState`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @NathanReed! Potentially the player could be walking around in the `ApproachingTargetCoordinateState` for a long time before hitting `IdleState`, so clearing it in `IdleState` is only a half solution I think. Also, if you consider the concept of "separation of concerns", `IdleState` ideally shouldn't know anything about trees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is as Nathan's comment, just identify when and where the values need to be cleaned up and do it manually there.

If you implement callback on the *edges* of a FSM rather than just the *nodes*, meaning chunks of code that are run on transition, then you can have a specific implementation of an edge from any of the `Tree` states to `Idle` allowing the idle state itself to be unaware of tree-specific details but allowing code to be reused for all of the possible ways into the idle state.

Another option is to use a hierarchical FSMs.  You could have one "parent" state that is the `Tree` state or `Idle` or `Combat` or whatnot, and then a number of sub-states for `Tree` including `Approaching`, `Cutting`, etc.  Now the variables are only stored in the `Tree` state so they are cleared/discarded when switching from `Tree` to `Idle`.  The substates should have easy access to their parent's shared data.

You can make a base `Targeting` state class/definition that `Tree`/`Combat`/etc derives from which can then allow some common code and even sub-states to be shared between tree cutting, combat, whatever since your targeting is likely going to be common.

Comment: Great advice. Really helps a lot. I understand your idea about implementing edge callbacks, but I'm not sure how you'd be able to reuse code that way. Could you elaborate on that? Also, you are insinuating that I should store state attributes on the state instances themselves. I thought that was bad practice (compared to storing it on the game entity object), have I misunderstood something?

Comment: There's no such thing as bad practice, only designs that don't work well for a particular solution.  That said, you could store them on the object and use on `OnExit` in a particular parent state to clean them up if you want, whatever works best for you.   So far as your other question, just focus on a data-driven design and it should fall out of that.